# Can't detach/ kill xm console on node server

Tags: virtual-machine, console, xen

Why can't I attach a console from the xm command?

> [root@vm ~]# xm console vm104 
>  Another console has already been
>   attached to guest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking for the process `xenconsole` and killing it. This should release the other `xm console ...` process that's consuming it.

```
$ pkill xenconsole
```

Now try your command:

```
$ xm console vm104
```

#### References

- [[Xen-users] how to take over console from another user?](http://lists.xen.org/archives/html/xen-users/2012-06/msg00336.html)